# Web Deployment build tool for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a SOAP server written in C++. In Visual Studio 2005 we used the "Web Deployment" build tool to deploy the DLL to the local IIS server (XP in my case).

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 I see that the VCWebDeploymentTool is no longer supported. What are my options now? Is there is command line tool I can use in a post build step to deploy a DLL locally?

I'm not looking for a web deployment "project". I'm looking for a web deployment build step. Purely for deploying to the local IIS on my build machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for the answer, I figured out you can still use the VC 2005 web deployment tool with VC 2010. The tool is called vcdeploy.exe, and can be found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin. Just copy this file to a directory that's in your PATH.

In VC 2005, the Web Deployment build tool is basically just a UI for vcdeploy. In VC 2010 I set up a custom build step to run vcdeploy.exe and now my .dll is deployed to the local IIS as it always was.

EDIT: Also note the vcdeploy source code is part of the ATL Server Library available here: http://atlserver.codeplex.com.